# Setting the background of an UIButton programmatically not working

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I'm just trying to simply set the background image of the button, but whatever I try it is doing nothing. I also put a `UIImageView` there to see if there's any issue with the image file, but the image view is set perfectly fine. Do I have to set something in the properties of the button?

Here the code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let imageToSet = UIImage(named: "3-1")
        
        b1.setBackgroundImage(imageToSet, for: .normal)
        
        imageView.image = imageToSet
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var b1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
}
```

These are my setting for the button:

[image: Button settings]

Comment: I'm wondering if it's because you are using a "System Button" Try to set it to custom maybe? And do you have really an image named `3-1` in your XCAssets?

Comment: Yes, the file is fine. The same image gets set in the UIImageView perfectly fine. Is it not possible to set the background of a "System Button" programmatically??

Comment: @user16071310  you can set background image in storyboard, it working

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Xcode 13 ,`UIButton` has four type are `Plain,Grain,Tinted,Filled` .When you create a button in storyboard , button type automatically set with `Plain` that means new UIButton configurations is on (If you set one of them 4).So when you try to use old behaviours like

```
setBackgroundImage(..)
setImage(..)
```

This functions not gonna effect on this button. So If you want to use old behaviours you need to set style `Plain` to `Default`

Comment: Thanks, that solved it!

Comment: add this too. button.configuration?.baseBackgroundColor = .red

Comment: To clarify for - for me I needed to set UIButton ***type*** to ***custom*** and also set ***style*** to ***default***.